# Select Join query does not work when executed by trigger

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join, triggers

Does anyone know why my join query inside of a trigger comes up empty?  However if I was to put this same query inside a stored procedure and run the store procedure outside of a trigger, it runs fine. BUT if you have a trigger execute this stored procedure with the join table, it comes up empty.  If you run the stored procedure directly in sql management studio, it pulls the data fine.  If you run the trigger withOUT the join and just a simple select on one table, it runs fine.

The problem seems to be when it does a select inside a trigger and has a Join.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Emergency  on dbo.Incident 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 



SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN

DECLARE @ID as int;

SELECT top 1 @ID=InsertedRow.Id FROM inserted InsertedRow;


    BEGIN
        Declare @g as varchar(255);
        --this doesn't work with JOIN 
        SELECT  @g=Link 
        FROM MyDataTable as Incident JOIN  MyOtherInformationTable 
        as Info on Incident.Id=Info.Id
        WHERE (Incident.Id=@ID);

        /* this works without join
        SELECT  @g=Link 
        FROM MyDataTable as Incident 
        WHERE (Incident.Id=@ID);
                    */

    END;

END;
```

Comment: How is your MyOtherInformationTable table gets populated? How are you expecting both tables IDs to be same?

Comment: It's populated by another system which have constraints on them.  MyOtherInformationTable can't exist without data from Incident table.  I should have specify it's more of a child table of incident.  The query I am running should return one record which it does if runs outside of a trigger but empty inside of a trigger.

Comment: That answers your problem. MyOtherInformationTable wont have record for same ID when you insert records to Incident table.

Comment: Do you always insert/update only one row of your table?, because if not, this trigger logic is flawed anyway (I mean, it should run, but it most likely won't do what you want)

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of understanding.  I just want to pull data from these two tables, not insert anything into it.  Basically the trigger figures what id was changed then pulls information base on that id.

Comment: @Lamak - Yes the system will only insert one at a time and you are right I shouldn't count on it; BUT I just want to get one to work before I worry about many....

Comment: @wirble Basically, what Vasanth is saying is that since you are just inserting rows on `MyDataTable` and you said that `MyOtherInformationTable` is a child table of the first one, then it is expected that that table doesn't have rows for that `id`  yet

Comment: OK I see what you guys are saying. DUH.  The moment the record is inserted, trigger kicks off before the child table gets populated and returns empty.  Is there a way to specify the dependency?

Comment: There is no way to do that in trigger, instead you can bundle the whole thing in a proc.

Comment: I do have it in a stored procedure which the trigger execute, but I run into the same problem since there are no data when the stored procedure execute.  I guess there is no way around it?

Comment: Yep, you can still return values from Incident table by doing a left join to MyOtherInformationTable. Updated my answer query based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below trigger will return newly inserted or updated records from incident with matching data in MyOtherInformationTable.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Emergency  on dbo.Incident 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

    select *
    from 
    inserted 
    left join MyOtherInformationTable on inserted.ID = MyOtherInformationTable.ID

END;
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer but it kind of defeats the purpose of joining it in the first place if we can't get information from the other table (at least on insert).  However, it's the limitation of the system and not the answer itself.  Thanks for your help.